# How to alter fields of the document body during query time in solr

Tags: solr

I have a document with below format.

```
          {
            "paramName0_s": "water_level",
            "paramValue0_s": "12.0"
            "paramName1_s": "battery_level",
            "paramValue1_s": "50.0"
          }
```

I want to edit this document for below format at query time. How could I do it?

```
          {
            "water_level": "12.0",
            "battery_level": "50.0"
          }
```

Comment: It'd be far easier if you could do this transformation when you're indexing values instead, since that would also allow you to use these values for searching. That being said, writing a custom [Document Transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html) might be an option (since I'm guessing you can't assume that `water_level` always corresponds to `paramValue0_s`)

Comment: Yeah. I can't guarantee that water_level always map to paramValue0_s. I need to write a generic query because I can't exactly say that there are this much of paramNames. I will try this. Thanks again.